# Lock free stack implementation in Python

Tags: python, stack, lock-free, compare-and-swap

Is it possible to implement lock free stack in Python? I have searched the web and didn't find a CAS function in Python.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned CAS and atomic operations in specific, but the standard implementation of Python(CPython) works with byte code and uses also a so-called global interpreter lock. So here are some insights why there are **no** atomic operations in Python and why there is no need for it.

**Global Interpreter Lock ([GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock))**

> In CPython, the global interpreter lock, or GIL, is a mutex that
>   prevents multiple native threads from executing Python bytecodes at
>   once.

That means, only **one** thread at a time can actually execute Python. When several threads are running, they rotate in their execution. Threads can release the gil only between bytecode instructions - so **not** in the middle of an executed instruction. Every instruction is already "atomic" from the view of a Python programm. But don't mix that with hardware atomic operations on the CPU, this is a level deeper. Behind every bytecode instruction, there are several assembler instructions which are executed.

Atomic operations are only necessary when you want to avoid that an operation like a compare-and-switch is not interrupted by any other thread. This can't happen in Python. A thread can interrupt another thread between the execution of instructions to create a compare-and-switch and then you have to use a thread instead.

A simple lock is necessary when you want to guarantee that a sequence of byte-code instructions / or Python function calls is executed without that another thread interrupts them.

Let's take a look at some source code and the corresponding bytecode instructions:

```
a = 0
b = 0
def func():
    global a
    global b

    # The const value 100 is loaded and stored in 'a'
    a = 100
    # 0 LOAD_CONST               1 (100)
    # 3 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (a)

    # The const value 200 is loaded and stored in 'b'
    b = 200
    # 6 LOAD_CONST               1 (200)
    # 9 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (b)
```

The function overwrites the global variables `a` and `b` with the values 100 and 200. If we would execute `func` from two threads, we can be sure that the values `a` and `b` will always be valid because the threads can just change between the bytecode instructions. If we would write this function in C, then `a` and `b` would have been atomic integers.

For me it seems [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects) is theclass you are looking for. It is a thread-safe stack which garantuess that an append or pop is executed without an interruption. Deques also support memory efficient appends and pops.

Comment: Thanks @HelloWorld . That's great, but does **deque** support CAS (compare and switch) atomic operation? That is essential in order to ensure lock-free implementation of a stack.

Comment: Please read my answer again. Python does not work like this. There is no need for it and there are no atomic operations. You need atomics when your environment supports real multithreading, this is not the case in CPython. When Python executes a bytecode instruction it says "write x into y", then **no** other thread can interrupt or do anything else in the meantime. You can be sure that the instruction is completely executed when the thread returns from executing this instruction. When you need a function that makes a compare-and-switch you have to use a lock - but again, this is not atomic.